# Create table on SQL Server from dynamic pivot results

Tags: sql-server, pivot, create-table

Is there a way to directly store the results of a dynamic pivot query into a fixed table? As the result is dynamic I can't create the table by specifying the columnnames and methods like "create table MyTable as (pivot select statement)" seem to fail on SQL server ("Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'"). 
I have tried to format the SQL below to get a SELECT - INTO - FROM structure but failed to do so. Any help is obviously greatly appreciated!

The SQL used for the pivot is (build thanks to this great website!):

```
declare @pivot varchar(max), @sql varchar(max)
create table pivot_columns (pivot_column varchar(100))

insert into pivot_columns
select distinct DateField from MyTable order by 1

select @pivot=coalesce(@pivot+',','')+'['+pivot_column+']'from pivot_columns

set @sql = 'SELECT * FROM (select DateField, RefCode, SumField from MyTable) p
PIVOT
(sum(SumField) FOR DateField IN  ( ' + @pivot + ') ) 
AS pvl'

drop table pivot_columns

exec (@sql)
```

Comment: Have you tried PRINTing `@sql` instead of/before executing it? What does the constructed script look like?

Comment: Hi Andriy,
I have but also did not get it to work from that. It is:
SELECT * FROM (select DateField, RefCode, SumField  from MyTable) p
PIVOT
(
sum(SumField)
FOR DateField IN
 ( [20110810],[20110815], ... ,[20110906],[20110907]) 
) AS pvl

Comment: And the pivot itself runs fine, it shows me what I want. I just want to store the results in a table for further editing/joining with other pivot table results.
And because it's a task that has to run automatically at some point, I don't want to manually create the table first and then use insert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I am not following what you are trying to do you should be able to add the `INTO mynewTable` to your sql that you are going to execute and you should get the new table.

```
declare @pivot varchar(max), @sql varchar(max)
create table pivot_columns (pivot_column varchar(100))

insert into pivot_columns
select distinct DateField from MyTable order by 1

select @pivot=coalesce(@pivot+',','')+'['+pivot_column+']'from pivot_columns

set @sql = 'SELECT * INTO mynewTable FROM (select DateField, RefCode, SumField from MyTable) p
PIVOT
(sum(SumField) FOR DateField IN  ( ' + @pivot + ') ) 
AS pvl'

drop table pivot_columns

exec (@sql)
```

I just test creating a new table in the following script and it gives me a new table that is in the DB for use:

```
create table t
( 
    [month] int, 
    [id] nvarchar(20), 
    [cnt] int 
)

insert t values (4,'TOTAL',214)
insert t values (5,'TOTAL',23)
insert t values (6,'TOTAL',23)
insert t values (4,'FUNC',47)
insert t values (5,'FUNC',5)
insert t values (6,'FUNC',5)
insert t values (4,'INDIL',167)
insert t values (5,'INDIL',18)
insert t values (6,'INDIL',18)


DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(month) 
            FROM t 
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT *
            INTO tabletest from 
            (
                select month, id, cnt
                from t
           ) x
            pivot 
            (
                 sum(cnt)
                for month in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '


execute(@query)

drop table t
```

Comment: Hi Bluefeet.
Thanks a lot! I don't understand why I struggled for hours but this is exactly what I meant and so simple in the end.

Comment: Got a dynamic pivot query figured out for myself but couldn't figure out an efficient way to dump it into a usable table.  Of course it was as simple as this!  Doh!!!!